# object space normal baking causes flat rendered faces in output texture

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normals, baking

[image: shading workspace]

Been searching a while looking at posts, but this seems different.

If you look at the top right quadrant, that's the matCap view of the surface, everything looks fine. I checked all normals. They're averaged, object shader smooth. Edges, vertices, faces all set to smooth. I cleared all seams, cleaned up all duplicate vertices. I looked though the geometry but can't find anything unusual like duplicate faces or edges.

But nothing seems to solve the issue you can see in the **lower left above**: blocky rendering of the faces, except of a few that seem to work.

..
..
..

It's like the edge normals are messed up., but I checked, they look okay.

[image: Normals on model]

I've tried a new UV map, and that seems to work, but the unwrapping is completely different. What is it about the UV map that would cause this problem?